# django_pylibmc complains under Django 1.7 and python 3.4

Tags: python, django, memcached

My environment:
Django 1.7
Python 3.2

As a disclaimer, I'm new to Django and Python.

I'm going through this [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache#start-using-memcache) in order to use Memcachier with Django.

The installion process didn't give me any errors, but when I fire up my tests with `./manage.py tests` I get the following error:

```
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_pylibmc/memcached.py", line 92
    except MemcachedError, e:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm looking at the python 3.x [docs for errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and it *seems* that line 92 of that file is indeed not valid syntax, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone suggest a possible fix?

Comment: Any reason why you are using django-pylibmc? Django comes with a pylibmc backend: `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache`

Comment: Also have you installed `libmemcached-dev`?

Comment: @AmirR. yes, I installed libmemcached-dev. I am using following this [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache#start-using-memcache) which suggested installing `django-pylibmc`.

Answer (score 0):

That library does not appear to be compatible with Python 3.

However, as Amir suggests, there is no need to use it anyway; Django comes with a pylibmc backend, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#memcached).

Comment: would that pylibmc backend work with the Memcachier Heroku addon?

Comment: @rexposadas Memcachier is just hosted memcached instances so unless they have some special API, any decent memcached client, pylibmc included, should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are following the Heroku docs which suggest using django-pylibmc, but Django supports Pylibmc out of the box with `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache`. Since these are just python wrappers over the pylibmc C libraries there should be really no reason to go with django-pylibmc.

Also if you look at the README (https://github.com/jbalogh/django-pylibmc#requirements) for django-pylibmc it states that it was written and tested with Python 2.7, so the use of Python 3 is also problematic here.

I applaud your efforts for using Python 3 with Django, but please make sure that all your third party apps are compatible and I highly recommend reading this from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/python3/