# Using Memcache in Django/Python 3,4 with Heroku

Tags: django, caching, heroku

I have been following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache#further-reading-and-resources) so that I can use Memcache on my app on Heroku. However I ran into issues when using `cache.get()` in Heroku's shell (it works fine on my end):

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_pylibmc/memcached.py", line 92
    except MemcachedError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189899/django-pylibmc-complains-under-django-1-7-and-python-3-4), who had the same issue as me. My `settings.py` looked like this:

```
def get_cache():
  import os
  try:
    os.environ['MEMCACHE_SERVERS'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_SERVERS'].replace(',', ';')
    os.environ['MEMCACHE_USERNAME'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_USERNAME']
    os.environ['MEMCACHE_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD']
    return {
      'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_pylibmc.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'TIMEOUT': 500,
        'BINARY': True,
        'OPTIONS': { 'tcp_nodelay': True }
      }
}
  except:
    return {
      'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'
      }
}
```

And so I replaced `django_pylibmc.memcached.PyLibMCCache` with `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache`. However then I got a different error when I tried `cache.get("foo")` again:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 84, in get

val = self._cache.get(key)

_pylibmc.ConnectionError: error 3 from memcached_get(:1:foo): (0x1c4ed40) CONNECTION FAILURE,  host: localhost:11211 -> libmemcached/get.cc:314
```

Could someone help me out? Is there some settings somewhere that I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax
`except MemcachedError, e:`
works in Python 2 but not Python 3.

Change it to `except MemcachedError as e:` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to switch to using Django's database cache instead.